# Allocating Memory Within A 2GB Range

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm writing a function that will allow the user to allocate memory within 2GB +/- of a specified address. I'm querying the memory to find a free page, and allocating there. This is for [x64 trampoline hooking](https://www.ragestorm.net/blogs/?p=107), since I'm using a relative jmp instruction.

My issue is that `NtQueryVirtualMemory` fails with a `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` error, thus always returns 0. I'm confused on why this is happening, because `min`(the lowest possible address) appears to be free when I check in Process Explorer.

```
LPVOID Allocate2GBRange(UINT_PTR address, SIZE_T dwSize)
{
    NtQueryVirtualMemory_t NtQueryVirtualMemory = (NtQueryVirtualMemory_t)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryVirtualMemory");

    UINT_PTR min, max;
    min = address >= 0x80000000 ? address - 0x80000000 : 0;
    max = address < (UINTPTR_MAX - 0x80000000) ? address + 0x80000000 : UINTPTR_MAX;

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi = { 0 };
    while (min < max)
    {
        NTSTATUS a = NtQueryVirtualMemory(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, min, MemoryBasicInformation, &mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION), NULL);
        if (a)
            return 0;

        if (mbi.State == MEM_FREE)
        {
            LPVOID addr = VirtualAlloc(mbi.AllocationBase, dwSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
            if (addr)
                return addr;
        }

        min += mbi.RegionSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a relative jump? If this is for hotpatching, you can reserve as many bytes as you want in each function header.

Comment: @Michael It is to patch NT APIs, and I chose the relative jump because I assumed there would be less fixups needed since the size is smaller, so less instructions overwritten.

Comment: Check my hotpatching article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043089/HotPatching-Deep-Inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at first several general notes (not about erroes)

very strange from my look mix `NtQueryVirtualMemory` with `VirtualAlloc`. exist sense or use

- `NtQueryVirtualMemory` with `NtAllocateVirtualMemory`

or

- `VirtualQuery` with `VirtualAlloc`

the `NtQueryVirtualMemory` have no any extra functionality compare to `VirtualQueryEx` (the `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` have extra functionality compare to `VirtualAllocEx` via `ZeroBits` parameter)

then if already use [`NtQueryVirtualMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryvirtualmemory) not need `GetProcAddress` - you can use static linking with *ntdll.lib* or *ntdllp.lib* from *wdk* - this api was, exist and will be exported from *ntdll.dll* like `VirtualQuery` exported from *kernel32.dll* and you link with *kernel32.lib* 
and if you anyway want use `GetProcAddress` - exist sense do this not every time when `Allocate2GBRange` is called, but once. and main check result of call - may be `GetProcAddress` return 0 ? if you sure that `GetProcAddress` never fail - you sure that `NtQueryVirtualMemory` always exported from *ntdll.dll* - so use static linking with *ntdll[p].lib*

then `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` in place `ProcessHandle` look very not native, despite correct. better use `NtCurrentProcess()` macro here or `GetCurrentProcess()`. but anyway, because you use kernel32 api - no any reason use `NtQueryVirtualMemory` instead `VirtualQuery` here

you not need zero init `mbi` before calls - this is out only parameter, and because initially always `min < max` better use `do {} while (min < max)` loop instead `while(min < max) {}`

---

now about critical errors in your code:

- use `mbi.AllocationBase` - when `mbi.State == MEM_FREE` - in this
  case `mbi.AllocationBase == 0` - so you tell [`VirtualAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc)
  allocate in **any** free space.
- `min += mbi.RegionSize;` - the `mbi.RegionSize` is from
  `mbi.BaseAddress` - so add it to `min` incorrect - you need use `min
  = (UINT_PTR)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize;`
- then in call `VirtualAlloc` (when lpAddress != 0) you **must** use
  `MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE` instead `MEM_COMMIT` only.

and about address which pass to `VirtualAlloc` - pass `mbi.AllocationBase` (simply 0) incorrect. but pass `mbi.BaseAddress` in case we found `mbi.State == MEM_FREE` region also not correct. why ? from `VirtualAlloc`

> If the memory is being reserved, the specified address is rounded down
>   to the nearest multiple of the allocation granularity.

this mean that `VirtualAlloc` really try allocate memory not from passed `mbi.BaseAddress` but from `mbi.BaseAddress & ~(dwAllocationGranularity - 1)` - smaller address. but this address can be already busy, as result you got `STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES` (`ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` win32 error) status.

for concrete example - let you have

```
[00007FF787650000, 00007FF787673000) busy memory
[00007FF787673000, ****************) free memory
```

and initially your `min` will be in `[00007FF787650000, 00007FF787673000)` busy memory region - as result you got `mbi.BaseAddress == 0x00007FF787650000` and `mbi.RegionSize == 0x23000`, because region is busy - you will try next region at `mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize;` - so at `00007FF787673000` address. you got `mbi.State == MEM_FREE` for it, but if you try call `VirtualAlloc` with `00007FF787673000` address - it rounded down this address to the `00007FF787670000` because now allocation granularity is `0x10000`. but `00007FF787670000` is belong to the `[00007FF787650000, 00007FF787673000)` busy memory region - al result `VirtualAlloc` fail with `STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES` (`ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`).

so you need use `(BaseAddress + (AllocationGranularity-1)) & ~(AllocationGranularity-1)` really - address rounded **up** to the nearest multiple of the allocation granularity.

all code can look like:

```
PVOID Allocate2GBRange(UINT_PTR address, SIZE_T dwSize)
{
    static ULONG dwAllocationGranularity;

    if (!dwAllocationGranularity)
    {
        SYSTEM_INFO si;
        GetSystemInfo(&si);
        dwAllocationGranularity = si.dwAllocationGranularity;
    }

    UINT_PTR min, max, addr, add = dwAllocationGranularity - 1, mask = ~add;

    min = address >= 0x80000000 ? (address - 0x80000000 + add) & mask : 0;
    max = address < (UINTPTR_MAX - 0x80000000) ? (address + 0x80000000) & mask : UINTPTR_MAX;

    ::MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi; 
    do 
    {
        if (!VirtualQuery((void*)min, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) return NULL;

        min = (UINT_PTR)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize;

        if (mbi.State == MEM_FREE)
        {
            addr = ((UINT_PTR)mbi.BaseAddress + add) & mask;

            if (addr < min && dwSize <= (min - addr))
            {
                if (addr = (UINT_PTR)VirtualAlloc((PVOID)addr, dwSize, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE))
                    return (PVOID)addr;
            }
        }


    } while (min < max);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was incredibly detailed, and the code works perfectly. The only issue is that your English needs a little bit of work, because I'm trying to understand some of your explanations and the grammar/word choices are a little bit wonky. Otherwise, this was fantastic and helped a lot. I'll re-read it a bunch of times and I'll probably eventually understand what you were trying to say in some parts. Thank you!

Comment: @MemeMachine - sorry for english. not my native language. have real problems with it

Comment: No worries. If your English was as good as your programming, you would be the best English teacher in the world :D

Comment: Oh and by the way, in your answer you asked why I used NtQueryVirtualMemory instead of VirtualQuery. Well, I was originally using VirtualQuery, but VirtualQuery was not returning any error message. I used GetLastError and it gave me nothing. So I switched to the Nt version so I could get an actual error code.

Comment: @MemeMachine - really `VirtualQuery` call `NtQueryVirtualMemory` - if it fail - `RtlNtStatusToDosError()` called - via this api original error `status` (you can get it via undocumented `RtlGetLastNtStatus()`) and translated win32 error (you can get it via `GetLastError()` saved in *TEB* and you got got both it. if `VirtualQuery` return true - this mean all ok - no errors. if it return false - the `GetLastError()` **never** return 0 in this case. you also can and call `RtlGetLastNtStatus();` win32 errors very frequently lost accuracy. yes i pesonally love use nt api because it return error code

Comment: @MemeMachine so `VirtualQuery` fail (return false) only if `NtQueryVirtualMemory` fail - return negative status. but not zero status never translated to 0 win32 error. in border case if specified NTSTATUS code does not have a corresponding system error code - `ERROR_MR_MID_NOT_FOUND`. [`RtlNtStatusToDosError`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-rtlntstatustodoserror) documented, while `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` not. however this is very useful for debug reason api and call it so easy as `GetLastError()`. and it frequently return more detail info for you

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. That will come in a lot of use in the future! By the way, with your answer you only try to allocate at the first base address. Does that mean we are missing out on potential free memory?

Comment: @MemeMachine - *only try to allocate at the first base address* - what you mean ? i increment `min`

Comment: If it fails to allocate with VirtualAlloc that means there was a race condition,
because it was free previously. You already set min before so would it ignore a bit of memory? Not a big deal on machines now because they have a lot of memory but just something I thought of

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188633/discussion-between-rbmm-and-meme-machine).