# How can mixed data types (int, float, char, etc) be stored in an array?

Tags: arrays, c, variant, heterogeneous-array, mixed-type

I want to store mixed data types in an array. How could one do that?

Comment: It's possible and there are use cases, but this is likely a flawed design. That's not what arrays are for.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

You can make the array elements a discriminated union, aka [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

```
struct {
    enum { is_int, is_float, is_char } type;
    union {
        int ival;
        float fval;
        char cval;
    } val;
} my_array[10];
```

The `type` member is used to hold the choice of which member of the `union` is should be used for each array element. So if you want to store an `int` in the first element, you would do:

```
my_array[0].type = is_int;
my_array[0].val.ival = 3;
```

When you want to access an element of the array, you must first check the type, then use the corresponding member of the union. A `switch` statement is useful:

```
switch (my_array[n].type) {
case is_int:
    // Do stuff for integer, using my_array[n].ival
    break;
case is_float:
    // Do stuff for float, using my_array[n].fval
    break;
case is_char:
    // Do stuff for char, using my_array[n].cvar
    break;
default:
    // Report an error, this shouldn't happen
}
```

It's left up to the programmer to ensure that the `type` member always corresponds to the last value stored in the `union`.

Comment: +1 This is the implentation of many interpreting languages written in C

Comment: @texasbruce also called a "tagged union". I'm using this technique too in my own language. ;)

Comment: Wikipedia uses a disambiguation page for "[discriminated union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminated_union)" - "disjoint union" in set theory and, as @H2CO3 mentioned, "tagged union" in computer science.

Comment: And the first line of the Wikipedia [Tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) page says: _In computer science, a tagged union, also called a variant, variant record, discriminated union, disjoint union, or sum type, ..._ It's been reinvented so many times it has many names (kind of like dictionaries, hashes, associative arrays, etc.).

Comment: @Barmar I've re-written it as "tagged union" but then read your comment. Rolled back the edit, I didn't mean to vandalize your answer.

Comment: +1 When I first found this question, I became excited because I had used tagged unions before to store "objects" of multiple data types in an array. Then I saw your answer... The only thing I would add is that having a switch on the enum type is useful inside an overloaded `operator<<` if you want to print out an object of union type, and you don't necessarily want `main()` to know what data type is inside the union. Like when you want to do a "dumb" loop that goes through all the elements in an array and prints them.

Comment: @Galaxy This is C, not C++. Modern C++ has better solutions like `std::variant`.

Answer (score 33):

Use a union:

```
union {
    int ival;
    float fval;
    void *pval;
} array[10];
```

You will have to keep track of the type of each element, though.

Answer (score 21):

Array elements need to have the same size, that is why it's not possible. You could work around it by creating a [variant type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

typedef enum __VarType {
  V_INT,
  V_CHAR,
  V_FLOAT,
} VarType;

typedef struct __Var {
  VarType type;
  union {
    int i;
    char c;
    float f;
  };
} Var;

void var_init_int(Var *v, int i) {
  v->type = V_INT;
  v->i = i;
}

void var_init_char(Var *v, char c) {
  v->type = V_CHAR;
  v->c = c;
}

void var_init_float(Var *v, float f) {
  v->type = V_FLOAT;
  v->f = f;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  Var v[SIZE];
  int i;

  var_init_int(&v[0], 10);
  var_init_char(&v[1], 'C');
  var_init_float(&v[2], 3.14);

  for( i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i++ ) {
    switch( v[i].type ) {
      case V_INT  : printf("INT   %d\n", v[i].i); break;
      case V_CHAR : printf("CHAR  %c\n", v[i].c); break;
      case V_FLOAT: printf("FLOAT %f\n", v[i].f); break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The size of the element of the union is the size of the largest element, 4.

Answer (score 8):

There's a different style of defining the tag-union (by whatever name) that IMO make it much nicer to *use*, by removing the internal union. This is the style used in the X Window System for things like Events.

The example in Barmar's answer gives the name `val` to the internal union. The example in Sp.'s answer uses an anonymous union to avoid having to specify the `.val.` every time you access the variant record. Unfortunately "anonymous" internal structs and unions is not available in C89 or C99. It's a compiler extension, and therefore inherently non-portable.

A better way IMO is to invert the whole definition. Make each data type its own struct, and put the tag (type specifier) into each struct.

```
typedef struct {
    int tag;
    int val;
} integer;

typedef struct {
    int tag;
    float val;
} real;
```

Then you wrap these in a top-level union.

```
typedef union {
    int tag;
    integer int_;
    real real_;
} record;

enum types { INVALID, INT, REAL };
```

Now it may appear that we're repeating ourselves, and we *are*. But consider that this definition is likely to be isolated to a single file. But we've eliminated the noise of specifiying the intermediate `.val.` before you get to the data.

```
record i;
i.tag = INT;
i.int_.val = 12;

record r;
r.tag = REAL;
r.real_.val = 57.0;
```

Instead, it goes at the end, where it's less obnoxious. :D

Another thing this allows is a form of inheritance. *Edit: this part is not standard C, but uses a GNU extension.*

```
if (r.tag == INT) {
    integer x = r;
    x.val = 36;
} else if (r.tag == REAL) {
    real x = r;
    x.val = 25.0;
}

integer g = { INT, 100 };
record rg = g;
```

Up-casting and down-casting.

---

*Edit:* One gotcha to be aware of is if you're constructing one of these with C99 designated initializers. All member initializers should be through the same union member.

```
record problem = { .tag = INT, .int_.val = 3 };

problem.tag; // may not be initialized
```

The `.tag` initializer can be ignored by an optimizing compiler, because the `.int_` initializer that follows *aliases* the same data area. Even though *we* know the layout (!), and it *should* be ok. No, it ain't. Use the "internal" tag instead (it overlays the outer tag, just like we want, but doesn't confuse the compiler).

```
record not_a_problem = { .int_.tag = INT, .int_.val = 3 };

not_a_problem.tag; // == INT
```

Comment: `.int_.val` doesn't alias the same area though because the compiler knows that `.val` is at a greater offset than `.tag` . Have you got a link to further discussion about this alleged problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can do a `void *` array, with a separated array of `size_t.` But you lose the information type.
If you need to keep information type in some way keep a third array of int (where the int is an enumerated value) Then code the function that casts depending on the `enum` value.

Comment: you can also store the type information [in the pointer itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504368/995714)

Answer (score 4):

Union is the standard way to go. But you have other solutions as well. One of those is [*tagged pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer), which involves storing more information in the *"free"* bits of a pointer.

Depending on architectures you can use the low or high bits, but the safest and most portable way is using the **unused low bits** by taking the advantage of aligned memory. For example in 32-bit and 64-bit systems, **pointers to `int` must be multiples of 4** (assuming `int` is a 32-bit type) and the 2 least significant bits must be 0, hence you can use them to store the type of your values. Of course you need to clear the tag bits before dereferencing the pointer. For example if your data type is limited to 4 different types then you can use it like below

```
void* tp; // tagged pointer
enum { is_int, is_double, is_char_p, is_char } type;
// ...
uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)tp & ~0x03; // clear the 2 low bits in the pointer
switch ((uintptr_t)tp & 0x03)           // check the tag (2 low bits) for the type
{
case is_int:    // data is int
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)addr));
    break;
case is_double: // data is double
    printf("%f\n", *((double*)addr));
    break;
case is_char_p: // data is char*
    printf("%s\n", (char*)addr);
    break;
case is_char:   // data is char
    printf("%c\n", *((char*)addr));
    break;
}
```

If you can make sure that the data is 8-byte aligned (like for pointers in 64-bit systems, or `long long` and `uint64_t`...), you'll have one more bit for the tag.

This has one disadvantage that you'll need more memory if the data have not been stored in a variable elsewhere. Therefore in case the type and range of your data is limited, you can store the values directly in the pointer. This technique has been used in the 32-bit version of **Chrome's V8 engine**, where it checks the least significant bit of the address to see if that's a *pointer to another object* (like double, big integers, string or some object) or a *31-bit signed value* (called [`smi` - small integer](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/an-introduction-to-speculative-optimization-in-v8)). If it's an `int`, Chrome simply does an arithmetic right shift 1 bit to get the value, otherwise the pointer is dereferenced.

---

On most current 64-bit systems the virtual address space is still much narrower than 64 bits, hence the **high most significant bits can also be used as tags**. Depending on the architecture you have different ways to use those as tags. [ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch12s05s01.html), [68k](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3426287) and many others can be configured to **ignore the top bits**, allowing you to use them freely without worrying about segfault or anything. From the linked Wikipedia article above:

> A significant example of the use of tagged pointers is the Objective-C runtime on iOS 7 on ARM64, notably used on the iPhone 5S. In iOS 7, virtual addresses are 33 bits (byte-aligned), so word-aligned addresses only use 30 bits (3 least significant bits are 0), leaving 34 bits for tags. Objective-C class pointers are word-aligned, and the tag fields are used for many purposes, such as storing a reference count and whether the object has a destructor.
>
> Early versions of MacOS used tagged addresses called Handles to store references to data objects. The high bits of the address indicated whether the data object was locked, purgeable, and/or originated from a resource file, respectively. This caused compatibility problems when MacOS addressing advanced from 24 bits to 32 bits in System 7.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer#Examples

On x86_64 [you can still use the high bits as tags with care](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16198700/995714). Of course you don't need to use all those 16 bits and can leave out some bits for future proof

In prior versions of Mozilla Firefox they also use *small integer optimizations* like V8, with the **3 low bits used to store the type** (int, string, object... etc.). But since JägerMonkey they took another path ([Mozilla’s New JavaScript Value Representation](https://evilpie.github.io/sayrer-fatval-backup/cache.aspx.htm), [backup link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100804173643/http://blog.mozilla.com/rob-sayre/2010/08/02/mozillas-new-javascript-value-representation/)). The value is now always stored in a 64-bit double precision variable. When the `double` is a ***normalized*** one, it can be used directly in calculations. However if the high 16 bits of it are all 1s, which denote an ***NaN***, the low 32-bits will store the address (in a 32-bit computer) to the value or the value directly, the remaining 16-bits will be used to store the type. This technique is called [*NaN-boxing*](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5145738) or nun-boxing. It's also used in 64-bit WebKit's JavaScriptCore and Mozilla's SpiderMonkey with the pointer being stored in the low 48 bits. If your main data type is floating-point, this is the best solution and delivers very good performance.

Read more about the above techniques: https://wingolog.org/archives/2011/05/18/value-representation-in-javascript-implementations