# Arrays of pointers and type conversions

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, mingw

I am doing a project which requires me to ***create arrays of non-homogeneous arrays***.

Say the array is "arr".

> Then arr[0] might be array of integers, arr[1] might be array of strings, etc.

For that purpose I am using pointers.
I have a base class:

```
 class base_class;
```

And then I have a template class

```
template<typename T>     
class temp_class : public base_class{ 
    private:
        T* ptr;
        .....
    public:
        void input(){
        //do something}
};
```

Now I define the class arr.

```
class arr{
    private:
        base_class* ptr;
        ....
    public:
        void take_data(){
            temp_class<int>* temp;
            temp = static_cast<temp_class<int>*> (ptr)//OR (ptr+1)
            temp->input();
        }
}
```

But I get a segmentation fault(or something similar). I guess that the problem is due to the fact that two different types of pointers are pointing to the same object and the "input" function makes sense in only one of them.

How do I fix this? Is there any other way I can implement my idea, without these error prone pointers?

Comment: Google _c++ discriminated union_

Comment: I'm getting results which relate to unions. Is the "discriminated union" a different form of "union"?

Comment: Yes, it's a union along with a separate field that lets you know the current type of the union value. See my most up-voted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577404/how-can-a-mixed-data-type-int-float-char-etc-be-stored-in-an-array/18577481#18577481

Answer (score 1):

One option for doing this would be to use an appropriately defined  Variant type from the Boost Variant C++ library as your array element.

The Boost documentation for Variant is available [at this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html)

There is a description of how to use a std::vector of Boost Variants in the basic tutorial at that link.