# C++ Reading Data into Memory when Data Format and Type is Unknown at Compile Time

Tags: c++, file-io

## Question

How do I read data into a vector inside a class if the data format from a filestream is unknown?

*(Note: ... as discussed in the comments ... if the file format type is `float`, then the file only contains `float` data. It cannot be a mix of `float` and `double`. - This will make sense after understanding the question below...)*

I am writing a C++ class to read data from a file in a specified format. For the purposes of this question, let us simplify the file format. It is described below.

- The first 4 bytes of the file form an `int`, this is used as a flag to specify the file data format.

  - If the `int` is 0, the file data is of type `float`.
  - If the `int` is 1, the file data is of type `double`.
- The next 4 bytes of the file form an `int`. This specifies the number of elements to be read into an array or `std::vector`.

However we do not know whether `std::vector<float>` or `std::vector<double>` is required in advance.

I have had an attempt at solving this problem for myself, however I removed the attempt because this question was attracting a large number of downvotes, and as discussed in the meta one possible reason for this was that the attempt as solving the problem was not complete. (However you can see my completed attempt in the answer below - it has some problems as discussed in the comments which have not yet been fixed.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577404/how-can-a-mixed-data-type-int-float-char-etc-be-stored-in-an-array/18577481#18577481

Comment: @Barmar That seems to be totally irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Why is that irrelevant? Make a vector of discriminated unions.

Comment: @Barmar I guess that could be a possible solution - you could add some code which implements a solution in that manner if you wish... but it doesn't seem sensible to me as there would be huge amounts of wasted memory for reading types such as `char` / `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Barmar I guess for me personally it's not a sensible solution. The question you linked is actually asking a totally different question, so I'm not sure why you added it.

Comment: Just to clarify here, this is not a question about being able to store multiple different types in the same array...

Comment: I misunderstood. Now I see that the file is uniform, either all int or all float, depending on the first 4 bytes.

Comment: @Barmar Okay fair enough... I can add a note about that if you like? (I did think it didn't make much sense, now I understand the confusion.)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the easiest way to solve this problem, but I think it would work. I kind of feel like I need to have more information and code in order to actually solve this problem, so this is all I can do with the information given:

I would read the integer (which denotes the data type in the file) into a `bool`. I would then pass it as an argument to some function like `vectorDataType` or something. In that function, use `if-else` statements and `typedef`. The `if-else` statements:

```
if (dataType == 0) {
    typedef float fileData;
}
else {
    typedef double fileData;
}
```

Now, you don't need to use type names, just the name you have defined as `float` or `double`.

```
std::vector<fileData>;
```

Not knowing the data type may create more problems in the program. But, assuming you don't need to know the data type outside of making the vector, this should be a good way to fix your present issue.