# C Linked lists storing different data types?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a school project and I am going to need multiple linked lists, each storing a value of a different type. So far I have this:

```
struct list_element
{
    struct list_element *next;
    int data;
};

struct list
{
    struct list_element *first;
};
```

And a few functions that work with it, like initList(struct list *), deleteList(struct list *), add(struct list *), etc.

But I would also need a list, that instead of int as data stores for example float.

What's the proper way to do this in C? Do I just make another struct (list2) and basically just copy and rename half of the functions that work with list? And have initList2(struct list2 *)...

Or should I create something like:

```
struct data
{
    void *data;
    char *data_type;
};
```

And store that in the list?

I don't like either of these, but I don't have another idea.

Comment: The `void *` technique probably needs the size as well as the pointer. The major problem is ensuring that the data stored in each list is homogeneous (because if it isn't, you need information to tell you about the type of each entry in the list, and that gets more complex still). The other suggestion can work reasonably well, especially if you can make the interface opaque to the clients. Do be ruthlessly systematic in the names of the sets of functions for each type. Think about whether you should migrate to C++ with its support for templates. Think about whether to emulate templates in C.

Comment: when you get to c++ (I hope you do) you will go 'aha thats why they have templates and generics,...I had to do that the hard way in C'

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There are no typedefs nor stray incomplete struct declarations in this question ... i double-checked ... you may go ahead and write an answer.

Comment: I know about C++ and it's templates, but because it is a school project, I have to do it in C.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577404/how-can-a-mixed-data-type-int-float-char-etc-be-stored-in-an-array/18577481#18577481. The question is about arrays, but the same technique can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at union type [Union](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm)

Comment: There are issues with unions.  For example, if you have `struct list_item { struct list_item *next; union u data; };` and `union u { int i; double d; char s[1024]; };`, then you waste an awful lot of space when you work with `int` or `double`.  You also need a discriminator to tell you what's stored in a given element.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is there a better way that doesn't waste space by reserving space for the largest type in the union?

Comment: @Barmar: in the specific case of character strings (arrays), you'd store a pointer and probably a length in the union, and allocate the big space separately.  That might well apply to structure types, too.  The other issue is knowing what you're storing pointers to — C won't care but your program will.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point, you should use `char *s` rather than `char s[SIZE]`. It's non-trivial, because then you have to worry about copying and freeing the string. That's why we get paid the big bucks :)