# Union storing previous part of program

Tags: c, linux, union

As asked on my assignment earlier I had to just right two functions part (a) was regarding "enum" and part b was regarding "struct"

Now its asking me to create a union that can store either
a. The enum in part(a)
b. The struct in part(b)
c. A single character.

i'm very confused.. What is this "either"?

Here I'm mentioning the code of part (a) & part (b)

a)

```
enum FavouriteFruits
{
    Cherries=4,
    Pears = 1,
    Berries = 2,
    Plums = 5
};

 int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    printf("Cherries are %d \n", Cherries);
    printf("Pears are %d \n" , Pears);
    printf("Berries are %d \n", Berries);
    printf("Plums are %d \n", Plums);

    return 0;
}
```

b)

```
struct realnumber
{
    float array [2][3];
    char* (*function)(int);
};
```

Comment: Have you read the explanation of what a `union` is in your textbook? It should be clear what they mean by "either".

Comment: A union is similar to a struct, except all of its members share the same storage.  So in general, only one member is active and valid at a time.  See your textbook for examples.

Comment: Yes my friend. I've read the explanation and still I'm confused and that't the reason I posted this question.. I'm not playing friend. 2 @Barmar

Comment: Okay.. But why does it say "store either" .. Do I not have to code for all three of them? or just select one of these out of three? @TomKarzes

Comment: It means you can store any one of them at a time.  At a later time, you can store a different one, at the expense of losing the previous one.  A union can store one of its members at a time.  There's no more to it than that.

Answer (score 0):

A union is a type that uses the same memory to hold a value that can be one of several different types.

```
union myUnion {
    enum FavouriteFruits ff;
    struct realnumber rn;
    char c;
};
```

You can now declare a variable of this type:

```
union myUnion u;
```

and assign to any of the members, just like assigning to a struct member.

```
u.c = 'a';
u.ff = Pears;
```

The difference from a `struct` is that they all share the same memory. When you assign to `u.ff`, it overwrites `u.c`. So you can only read from the same member that you last assigned to. It's your responsibility to keep track of which member that was. See [How can a mixed data type (int, float, char, etc) be stored in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577404/how-can-a-mixed-data-type-int-float-char-etc-be-stored-in-an-array/18577481#18577481) for a technique called a *tagged union* that can be used for this.