# How did python implement Type free variables from a statically typed language

Tags: python, c

I know most of python is implemented in C. I was wondering that how does python work under the hood(in terms of its implementation in C) when it comes to determining what type of variable it is in this case lets say `x = 5` now if the check the type of x it will say class int but how is that implemented in C?
What checks are made under the hood to determine that it belongs to Class int

Comment: I'm far from an expert on compiler/interpreter construction, but void pointers in C can point to data of any type, so I don't see an obvious issue with Python being dynamically typed. Although it is presumably more complicated than "line X in Python becomes line(s) Y in C".

Comment: "I know most of python is implemented in C" – That is wrong. The majority of Python implementations does not use C. IronPython uses C#, Jython uses Java, PyPy uses RPython.

Comment: @JörgWMittag OP is clearly referring to the reference implementation CPython, which most people mean when they speak about Python and is, as the name suggests, implemented in C.

Comment: You might want to check out one of my most upvoted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577404/how-can-mixed-data-types-int-float-char-etc-be-stored-in-an-array/18577481#18577481

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a huge subject.

The below document will give you more understanding.

https://intopythoncom.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/internalsofcpython3-6-1.pdf

Like you said a simple example for integer types

To hold an integer type object, there is structure defined in C as said below

```
typedef struct {
PyObject_HEAD
long ob_ival;
} PyIntObject;
```

The object of C structure `PyIntObject` (section 7.5 of above said document) holds the objects which are integer type.

If you are more interested, setup the environment and debug as said in same section 7.5 of the above document.

> Objects/intobject.c and place a debug point on line number 89. Start
> debugging the application.

**PyTypeObject** is at higher level for the types to be represented. (look section 7.3 of above said document)

As a programmer, it is curious aspect to know the internals. But do not spend too much time to understand unless you work at interpreter level.

Answer (score 17):

Python is in no way "type free" (see "[Is Python strongly typed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328980/2402272)").  All Python objects have a specific type that determines many of their properties and behaviors.  For those that are represented as literals, that type is determined by their lexical form.  For other objects, it is determined by how they were computed.

What Python does not have is type *declarations* or any other built-in form of limiting or predetermining the type of objects that a variable or aggregate may contain.  Thus it does not make sense to talk about the type of a variable, such as your `x`, but only about the type of the value that it contains.  And that is what the `type()` function (for example) computes.  So when you ask

> how does python work under the hood(in terms of its implementation in C) when it comes to determining what type of variable it is

the answer is in one sense simple: Python doesn't do that at all.  *Variables* don't have types -- only their values do.  When you call, say, `type(x)`, you are not determining the type of the variable, but rather the type of its current value.

And Python supports that by ensuring that every Python object, such as one represented by the literal `5`, contains rather a lot of data.  Significantly, it contains information about the object's value *and type*, but it also contains various other details as well, such as a reference count and much more.  The details are much too broad for an SO answer, but you can find a lot of them in the [Python / C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html).  For the deepest and most intimate secrets, you would want to study the cpython headers and source.