# C access enum from struct

Tags: c, struct, enums, unions

My problem is that `car_name_str` could not be resolved. Why is it not callable and I want to keep the code structure?

I want to keep the structure as struct with union and enum (different datatypes).

Template: [How can mixed data types (int, float, char, etc) be stored in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577404/how-can-mixed-data-types-int-float-char-etc-be-stored-in-an-array)

```
//car_union.h
    typedef struct {
        enum { number_of_seats_int, car_cost_float, car_name_str } type;    
        union {
            int number_of_seats;
            float car_cost;
            char* car_name;
            } value;
    }Car_data_ex[30][3];   

    extern Car_data_ex *Car_data[30][3];

//fill_car.c
#include "car_union.h"
Car_data_ex *Car_data[30][3];
Car_data[0][0]->type = car_name_str;  //-> because pointer but doesnt work
Car_data[0][0]->value->car_name= "land rover";

Car_data[0][1]->type = car_cost_float;    //doesnt work
Car_data[0][1]->value->car_cost= 45000;
```

Comment: Why do you have the `[30][3]` at the declaring of the type?

Comment: if i only need 30 times 3 values(float car_cost, str car_name, int number_of_seats)

Comment: In the linked answer they declare a variable directly with an anonymous type, you declare a type and then declare a variable using this type.

Comment: i am not sure, but the only difference is the pointer?and how can I do it right ?

Comment: But... `Car_data[0][0]->` that pointer is uninitialized. Don't want to have 90  __cars__, not 90 __pointers__ to cars?

Comment: Just curious, why are you using this tagged union instead of a struct?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `[30][3]` from the type def, like [this](https://tio.run/##fZHLboMwEEX3/opRummjEojSrCjZ9DMQsoyZNKhgR36kqSK@nY4peRBV8cLSXHvOvR7LSDZCffb9U61k4yuEd@uqWi92G8biWArDvaq1WuyY@9ljhVuwznjp4MSAFirfwgloL9FwveUWhbO8Vu4VQrPU1vFto8VYK9EiJwJ0EHhpYAygwWWEhkWEe2p6ORyAF/5Vlzth5hefP72Dg2g8Fd0H6ZVwguMx@DKGR4dGwY0O83ORr5IiXxUpYyFJK2r1/DLGe3z/9kZOWlJEm/BUyCYDoARxHG2gRCm8Rdhr8kEDpXdQabRk@q3N17@44UGLMy2DGX1hBUYf0Mwo8H3Lcprg@iXD9OP4kd1yYhdaM3hbJ0lC8@z7Xw)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

//car_union.h
typedef struct {
    enum { number_of_seats_int, car_cost_float, car_name_str } type;    
    union {
        int number_of_seats;
        float car_cost;
        char* car_name;
    } value;
}Car_data_ex;   

extern Car_data_ex *Car_data[30][3];

int main() {
    Car_data_ex *Car_data[30][3];
    Car_data[0][0]->type = car_name_str;  //-> because pointer but doesnt work
    Car_data[0][0]->value.car_name= "land rover";

    Car_data[0][1]->type = car_cost_float;    //doesnt work
    Car_data[0][1]->value.car_cost= 45000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what's in your struct, when you do

```
typedef struct Car_dataStructTag{
    //...
}Car_data_ex[30][3];
```

(I've tagged the struct so it can be referred to by `struct Car_dataStructTag`),
then `Car_data_ex` is a *type alias* resolving to `struct Car_dataStructTag [30][3]`
which means

```
extern Car_data_ex *Car_data[30][3];
```

is fully equivalent to

```
extern struct Car_dataStructTag (*Car_data[30][3])[30][3];
```

which means `Car_data[x][y]` is a pointer to a two-dimensional array of `struct Car_dataStructTag`,
which is definitely not something you can apply `->` to.

Try:

```
typedef struct Car_dataStructTag{
    //...
}Car_data_ex[30][3];
extern Car_data_ex *Car_data[30][3];
extern struct Car_dataStructTag (*Car_data[30][3])[30][3];
```

in a compiler -- it gets accepted, confirming the declaration equivalence.

Running into situations such as this one is why it's generally considered ill-advisable to `typedef` arrays or pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You have over complexified everything.

A typedef is just to give an alias to a (complex) type. Here the type is a struct containing an enum and an union. So it should be:

```
typedef struct {
    enum { number_of_seats_int, car_cost_float, car_name_str } type;
    union {
        int number_of_seats;
        float car_cost;
        char* car_name;
        } value;
}Car_data_ex;
```

Next, using an array of pointers can make sense, but provided each pointer in the array does point to a true object. Here you only want a plain (2D) array:

```
Car_data_ex Car_data[30][3];
```

Once this has been done, you can write with no error or warning:

```
Car_data[0][0].type = car_name_str;
Car_data[0][0].value.car_name= "land rover";

Car_data[0][1].type = car_cost_float;
Car_data[0][1].value.car_cost= 45000;
```

And you should avoid `extern Car_data_ex Car_data[30][3];`. It *declares* a global array, that will have to be *defined* in one single compilation unit (.c file). Here again, it can make sense, but IMHO it is a rather advanced feature that can be hard to correctly use. And nothing in the shown code lets think that is is required...

Comment: @herr_mueller12 You're welcome. #inclusion is pretty much no different from pasting the definitions at the place of your `#include`. Try this shell-created test setup to see that it works (works on a directory named `include_test.d`, which you shouldn't have in your current directory): https://pastebin.com/8td3MThx