# Is there a simpler way to get data type from user to calculate the result

Tags: c

This program should ask the user a type of number he will input (int or double), and calculate the result by using a formula

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double calculate_expression(int n, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, n);

    double result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int type = va_arg(args, int);

        if (type == 0) { 
            int x = va_arg(args, int);
            result -= x * x / (double)i;
        } else if (type == 1) { 
            double x = va_arg(args, double);
            result += x * x / i * (i % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1);
        }
    }

    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Введіть кількість чисел у числовій послідовності: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\nВведіть тип елементу (0 для цілих, 1 для дробових), а потім елемент:\n");

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        int type;
        double x;

        printf("%d елемент: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &type);

        if (type == 0) {
            scanf("%lf", &x);
        } else if (type == 1) {
            scanf("%lf", &x);
        }

        calculate_expression(1, type, x);
    }

    double result = calculate_expression(n);
    printf("\nResult: %lf\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is i cannot get int type to work (it will always output zero, when i get even one int into the equation), is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You're always reading and passing in a `double`

Comment: @ICantComeUp, `if (type == 0)` and `else if (type == 1)` both call `scanf("%lf", &x);`.  Why the same?

Comment: It seems you're looking for a generic [with dynamic polymorphism] in C. See my answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650) Adapting from there, you'd want to implement virtual functions for scanning, calculation, printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need different variables in the caller so you can ask the user for different types in your `if` and `else` blocks.

You'll also have to move the call to `calculate_expression()` inside the `if/else` blocks so it can use the appropriate variable type.

```
int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Введіть кількість чисел у числовій послідовності: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\nВведіть тип елементу (0 для цілих, 1 для дробових), а потім елемент:\n");

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        int type;

        printf("%d елемент: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &type);

        double result;
        if (type == 0) {
            int x;
            scanf("%d", &x);
            result = calculate_expression(1, type, x);
        } else if (type == 1) {
            double x;
            scanf("%lf", &x);
            result = calculate_expression(1, type, x);
        }
    }

    printf("\nResult: %lf\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Your `calculate_expression()` function allows for an arbitrary length list of type/value pairs that it will iterate over. Implementing that in the caller will be difficult, since it's not possible to create variadic argument lists dynamically. You would need distinct blocks of code for every possible combination of input types.

A better solution would be to use an array of discriminated unions. See [How can mixed data types (int, float, char, etc) be stored in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577404/how-can-mixed-data-types-int-float-char-etc-be-stored-in-an-array/18577481#18577481)