# Save pointer to differents type in a std::vector while iterating

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Consider the following function (myfct). When this function returns, data points to either uint16_t, float_t or double_t.

In main(), this function is called in a for loop. I want for each iteration to save "data" in a std::vector with the type it points to. How can I do that?  Thanks in advance.

PS: the container must not necessarily be a vector, it can be anything else, I just want to save "data" without loosing the pointer type information.

```
void myfct(void*&data, int id) {
if(id==1) {
  uint16_t* ptr = ...;  
  data = ptr;
}
else if(id==2) {
  float_t* ptr = ...;  
  data = ptr;
}
else if(id==3) {
  double_t* ptr = ...;  
  data = ptr;
}
}

int main() 
{
    void* dataPtr = nullptr;
    vector<?> myVec; //how should I template my vector? which typename?
    for(int i = 0, i<5, i++) 
    {
        myfct(dataPtr , i);  //note that dataPtr is passed by reference
        myVec.push_back(dataPtr ); //here dataPtr point to either uint16_t, 
        //float_t or double_t. I want to save it with the type it point to.
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is `std::variant` or `std::any`.

Comment: Whenever you are using a `void *` in C++ you are *very likely* doing it wrong.

Comment: A `std::vector` can only hold data of *one* type.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  the container muss not be a vector, it can be anything else, I just want to save "data" without loosing the pointer type information.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm unfortunately limited to c++11

Comment: @Gaetan The "one type per container" bit goes for *all* the standard containers, not just `vector`. If you want multiple types, use multiple containers (or containers of `variant` or `any` as Nathan suggested).

Comment: *I want to save it with the type it point to.* You probably want 3 vectors, one for each type.

Comment: @Gaetan Boost has C++11 compatible versions.

Comment: if you already have the data stored somewhere and just need to store to pointers, you can [store the type of the variable in the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16198700/995714). Otherwise if you want to get data, use `std::variant` as Nathan said above

Comment: @phuclv std::variant is a c++17 feature. I'm trying to use boost::variant. will let you guys know if it worked. Thanks for the replies. Some others idea maybe?

Comment: @Gaetan you might want to look at using a linked list instead of a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to `std::variant`, the way to do it would be the following:

```
class custom_type {
    int id;
    union data_holder
    {
        uint16_t i;
        float_t f;
        double_t d;
    } data;
}
```

Now, you can have a `vector<custom_type>`, and if you want to work with a data point, you can do

```
custom_type c = myvec.back();
if( c.id == 1 ) {
    uint16_t val = c.data.i;
    // Process val in a uint way
} else if( c.id == 2 ) {
    float_t val = c.data.f;
    // Process val in a float way
} ...
```

You can learn more about unions [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). Now, in order to make your code handle the data types easily (So you don't have to write the similar "process val in an X way" over and over again), you can use [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/). For example,

```
template <typename T>
T calculate(T val) {
    // Do stuff with val
    return computed_val;
}
```

And now,

```
custom_type c = myvec.back();
if( c.id == 1 ) {
    uint16_t val = calculate<uint16_t>(c.data.i);
    cout << val;
} else if( c.id == 2 ) {
    float_t val = calculate<float_t>(c.data.f);
    cout << val;
} ...
```

Comment: `std::variant` is just a wrapper around a union anyway. If you _need_ it to be a pointer as shown in your question, then you can have the union encapsulate pointers instead of the types themselves. I don't think that's the right way to go about it though, you should just have a pointer to `custom_type` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is *polymorphism*, e.g., a base class (can be an interface/abc) and then derived classes, which implement some `typeof` functor. I can give an example if you wish to, but I think it would be a lot more valuable for you to learn how to do it yourself.
Another way is to use `boost::variant` or `boost::any`.